# How do I know whether my database is in serializable mode?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I understand that you can look at the dmv sys.databases to get isolation information:

```
 select name
        , s.snapshot_isolation_state
        , snapshot_isolation_state_desc
        , is_read_committed_snapshot_on
        , recovery_model
        , recovery_model_desc
        , collation_name
    from sys.databases s
    ORDER BY 1
```

I'm not understanding how we can use information from sys.databases to determine the isolation mode. **How do you know what type of isolation mode is currently set on for the database?**

Comment: note the database setting is used only when no value is specified when connecting.  AFAIL, all modern APIs set the default transaction level to read committed so the database setting will have no affect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databases in SQL Server don't have a default isolation level. What you're seeing in sys.databases is whether the database *allows* snapshot isolation and whether read committed is optimistic (i.e. uses snapshots to enforce read committed) or pessimistic. Absent any application setting it differently, the default isolation level is read committed regardless of the database.

Answer (score 2):

DBCC UserOptions (Check "isolation level")

> Returns the SET options active (set) for the current connection.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180065.aspx

---

```
DBCC UserOptions
```

---

```
+-------------------------+----------------+
| Set Option              | Value          |
+-------------------------+----------------+
| textsize                | 2147483647     |
+-------------------------+----------------+
| language                | us_english     |
+-------------------------+----------------+
| dateformat              | mdy            |
+-------------------------+----------------+
| datefirst               | 7              |
+-------------------------+----------------+
| lock_timeout            | -1             |
+-------------------------+----------------+
| quoted_identifier       | SET            |
+-------------------------+----------------+
| arithabort              | SET            |
+-------------------------+----------------+
| ansi_null_dflt_on       | SET            |
+-------------------------+----------------+
| ansi_warnings           | SET            |
+-------------------------+----------------+
| ansi_padding            | SET            |
+-------------------------+----------------+
| ansi_nulls              | SET            |
+-------------------------+----------------+
| concat_null_yields_null | SET            |
+-------------------------+----------------+
| isolation level         | read committed |
+-------------------------+----------------+
```

---

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
```

---

```
DBCC UserOptions
```

---

```
+-------------------------+--------------+
| Set Option              | Value        |
+-------------------------+--------------+
| textsize                | 2147483647   |
+-------------------------+--------------+
| language                | us_english   |
+-------------------------+--------------+
| dateformat              | mdy          |
+-------------------------+--------------+
| datefirst               | 7            |
+-------------------------+--------------+
| lock_timeout            | -1           |
+-------------------------+--------------+
| quoted_identifier       | SET          |
+-------------------------+--------------+
| arithabort              | SET          |
+-------------------------+--------------+
| ansi_null_dflt_on       | SET          |
+-------------------------+--------------+
| ansi_warnings           | SET          |
+-------------------------+--------------+
| ansi_padding            | SET          |
+-------------------------+--------------+
| ansi_nulls              | SET          |
+-------------------------+--------------+
| concat_null_yields_null | SET          |
+-------------------------+--------------+
| isolation level         | serializable |
+-------------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: would that be for the current transaction or would it be the default db setting?

Comment: thank you very much. when setting the transactional isolation level for a specific transaction, will it override the database default?

Comment: Yes, but is per connection, not per transaction. After you commit,rollback the isolation level stays as it was defined within the transaction and does not return to its value before the transaction.